# Start Google Maps Activity for Result

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app, the user must select a location on the Google Map, so I want to start the built-in Google Map app with a `startActivityForResult` call, and then the user selects a location and the app returns to my app giving me the GPS coordinates of the selected point inside `onActivityResult` function.

Is that possible?

Comment: So, what you are asking is if you can fire off an intent to another application and then have that application return some data for you to use? If so, you'll need to see that application supports that. So you'll need to read/find an API for the actual google maps app to see if that is possible. My guess is that it probably isn't as they (Google) would probably prefer you just use a maps object in your application,etc.

Comment: It is posible. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34571187/2835520) is the solution