# how to start google map for result

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, onactivityresult

I want my user to enter an address. But I want the address to be confirmed with Google Map. So when the user clicks on a button to enter the address, I want to launch an Intent for Google Map where user can enter the address. But then I want the map to return the data to me. How do I do that? If I start my activity as

```
Uri searchUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?z=10&q=");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,searchUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivityForResult(mapIntent,RESULT_CODE_LOCATION);
```

number one, will it do what I seek? Second: how do I implement `onActivityResult`? I need the human readable address and the lat-long.

**To be clear: I want the user to enter the address through Google Map and then have the address returned to my app.**

Answer (score 3):

I figure it out. I have to use PlacePicker to accomplish what I seek. https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker

Comment: umm.. don't accept it, PlacePicker is now deprecated and will be turned off on 29 July 2019

Comment: placepicker is updated... you just need to migrate to new version

Comment: @SamirElekberov, Its not updated. Just have a look at the pricing even for every search that you made.. For example, it is 40USD/1000 searches. If you are still able to do that, then please share your code snippet that would be really helpful.